# spring-data-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb and JPA not working together

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

We are developing a micro-service based on Spring that need to work with both DynamoDB and MySQL. As an example I took this simple ["DynamoDB in a Spring"](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb) example and everything worked fine. Then I wanted to add the MySQL part but as soon as I added this to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring stoped working complaining that the `productInfoRepository` isn't a managed type:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productInfoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.baeldung.spring.data.dynamodb.model.ProductInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

`basePackageClasses` of `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I can confirm this. I also had to use `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.package.repository"})` where the location of the package pointed to where my non-dynamo repositories were stored.